# Should tags such as [firing] be sacked?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just removed the tag [firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firing) from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564495/all-items-in-if-statement-not-firing) because it is useless IMO.

This tag is also used in several other questions (such as "why is my event not firing", etc). And I guess there are lots of other similar tags.

Is there a general rule what should be done with such tags? Remove them from all questions (assuming it doesn't add anything useful to the question)? Or notify and admin to delete the tag?

Comment: Hmm, what's so useful about [if-statement]?   It is just a hapless user that can't think of anything better.  That doesn't require the authorities to be alerted or the system to be overhauled.

Comment: It has no wiki and only 57 questions, I'd be inclined to burninate it.

Comment: [Burn It to the ground](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xhGG7.gif)

Comment: Generally instead of removing tags, replace them with something better.  For that particular question, "timers" and "messagebox" would both be relevant.

Comment: This is begging for a punny title... (Burniate, fire and so on)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think you missed it: "Firing" can mean to forcibly remove someone from from his or her job. "Sacked" is a euphemism for being fired.

Comment: Would [tag:events]  be a suitable replacement?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Burninate it with firing?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SII-jhEd-a0

Comment: I should've mentioned this *before* the mass burning, but if you do edit any of these questions, **edit anything else on the question that needs it.**  Just editing the tags isn't sufficient in most cases.

Comment: @Makoto: in this specific case, I thought the rest of the question was OK

Answer (score 5):

The firing squad has gone forth and exterminated the [firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firing) tag.

[image: ***TROGDOR***]

Answer (score 0):

Dracarys.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ...answered the user who doesn't fear downvotes ;)

Comment: @honk: Meh, it's only meh-ta. If you don't garner downvotes on meh-ta you're doing something wrong.

Comment: This is why I actually didn't downvote ;)

Comment: @honk: I shall always re-meh-mber you.

Comment: I'm already your fan since a long time :)

Comment: @honk: I'm glad to hear that, meh friend.

Comment: According to your answer the title of the question should be: "A Song of Ice and [Firing]".

Comment: @honk: pahahahaha

Comment: I don't understand that reference

Comment: @acbabis: Then your username should be "Jon Snow".

Comment: GOT... @acbabis

Comment: @J-S I didn't understand that reference either, so I looked it up and it stands for Game of Thrones.